# Not sure how to set the correct path to an image in back-ground image

Tags: html, css

Currently I just wanna put an image as back-ground to a div. I can access the image in my browser by typing `http://example.com/storage/uploads/icons/heart.png` but I am not sure what to write in my `background-image: url("");` since I'm using Laravel for back-end and I'm not sure where exactly I am in the folder hierarchy by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **A)** if `http://example.com/` is'nt the root of your domain:

```
background-image: url("http://example.com/storage/uploads/icons/heart.png");
```

for example:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRDAYrQr9qgT2W00EV_CoCahFki3Vw4lSMNt81k9FCSTXoKT8TY2w");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

> **B)** if `http://example.com/` is your domain, so depending on the html file location to the `storage` folder ,for example: if path `storage` folder and `html` file be same,use this:

```
background-image: url("storage/uploads/icons/heart.png");
```

> **C)** if path `html` file is: `http://example.com/HtmlFolder/index.html` and path `image` is  `http://example.com/storage/uploads/icons/heart.png`,so use `../` a folder to go back:

```
background-image: url("../storage/uploads/icons/heart.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any image as background in Html using either  **url() or href=""** attributes of  tag. As you mentioned a web link you can pass the same link as parameter to one of the above mentioned attributes and it will work perfectly as long as your application has an internet access.

Comment: But this way I'd hard code it and if I change the domain name, I'd have to change code as well.